# Can Visual Studio 2005 (C++) treat undefined preprocessor symbols as an error

Tags: visual-studio

VS2005 is very long in the tooth, but it is the tool I have to use.

My preference is to require that all preprocessor symbols be defined, but I can't find a way to cause VS2005 to generate an error if an undefined preprocessor symbol is referenced.

e.g.
in moo.h

```
#define _DEFN_WITH_TYPOE (1)
```

in cow.cpp

```
#include "moo.h"
#if _DEFN_WITH_TYPO
    [various code bits]
#endif // _DEFN_WITH_TYPO
```

should generate an error, rather than treating _DEFN_WITH_TYPO as defined with value 0.

Is there an option that will do this?

TIA.